# Genymotion Cannot Connect to VirtualBox Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm trying to use Genymotion Android as my android emulator in conjunction with Oracle's VirtualBox Software on my mac. I created a Nexus 5 4.4.2 virtual device that worked a few days ago, but now every time I run Genymotion, I get the following:

```
Unable to connect to your virtual device! Genymotion will now stop. Check your VirtualBox network configuration.

For more information refer to: https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-nostart
```

I haven't changed anything in VirtualBox over the last few days, and in fact when I open VirtualBox, it shows the virtual device being run in it's preview frame, but I can't get it to run in Genymotion. Any thoughts??

Comment: have you tried this already? https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-nostart

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in Ubuntu , it was solved by re installing Virtual Box DKMS kernel module, a similar solution must exist in Mac also.